# Emacs buffer-menu: how to show only file + dired buffers?

Tags: emacs

I use buffer-menu extensively to switch between buffers. I want to list the buffers which are files or dired. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [ibuffer](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IbufferMode)

There you can define your buffer groups. You can mark buffers, use filtering and sorting, do search/replace in marked buffers and other useful stuff.

For your case just put into the hook `(ibuffer-filter-by-filename ".")`

Here is an example from my .emacs .

```
(require 'ibuffer)

(setq ibuffer-saved-filter-groups
      (quote (("default"
               ("dired" (mode . dired-mode))
               ("java" (mode . java-mode))
               ("org" (mode . org-mode))
               ("sql" (mode . sql-mode))
               ("xml" (mode . nxml-mode))))))    

(setq ibuffer-show-empty-filter-groups nil)

(add-hook 'ibuffer-mode-hook 
 (lambda () 
  (ibuffer-switch-to-saved-filter-groups "default")
  (ibuffer-filter-by-filename "."))) ;; to show only dired and files buffers
```

EDIT. If you want to filter out temporary buffers (which name begins with *) you can set the following filter (regex)

```
(ibuffer-filter-by-name "^[^*]")
```

It says that the buffer name should start with any character except *.

Comment: I like this one. But `(ibuffer-filter-by-filename ".")` is also filtering out dired buffers.

Comment: In ibuffer window you can see three columns. I set a filter that this column's value should be not empty (which is the case for dired buffers and files). What is shown in your case in the Filename/process column for dired buffers?

Comment: I see 4 columns: "MR", "Name", "Size", "Mode", "Filename/process". In the "Filename/process" column I see "~/Dropbox/" for a dired buffer.

Comment: I think it'll be easier if I can exclude all buffers starting with a "*". Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Yes, please see my EDIT in the answer

Answer (score 2):

[***Buffer Menu+***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BufferMenuPlus) has what you want.  It treats Dired buffers like file buffers, so when you use <kbd>C-u C-x C-b</kbd> (either `list-buffers` or `buffer-menu`) you get only Dired and file buffers.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `buffer-menu` with a prefix argument (`C-u M-x buffer-menu`) will list only buffers which are visiting files. Unfortunately I can't see an easy way to include dired in that list.